# How do I change default Devise views paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise

I am developing a Rails project with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). By default all Devise views go to `app/views/devise/...`
I would like instead, to have them in `/app/views/users/...` like:

- `app/views/users/sessions`
- `app/views/users/registration`
- etc.

I got as far as `rails generate devise:views users`, but there is also some code change involved.

I don't want to change the controllers. I just want to have views in a different directory than the default one.

Comment: Why do you want it like that? I guess you've your reason for that, but maybe you can get what you want without changing that... BTW, didn't checked... but all this kind of questions are quite well answered in the devise wiki on github https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think without changing the controller you cant change the default folder for devise views.
I suggest if you want to have different views then just make your changes in devise views.