# What does this mean "Missing template" (ruby, rails 4, devise 2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm a newbie and don't understand where this error message:

```
Missing template customer_mailer/confirmation_instructions with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "customer_mailer"
```

Where is it expecting the template to be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message tells you need a view called `confirmation_instructions.html.*` in your `app/views/customer_mailer/` path.

The `*` must be changed according to your handler: `erb`, `haml`, etc.

Comment: my devise views for customers are INSIDE a customers folder: the pages such as views/customers/confirmations/new.html.erb AND the views of the Customers devise e-mails such as views/customers/customer_mailer/confirmations_instructions.html.erb. How can i tell Devise to look there and not in views/customer_mailer path ?

Comment: Check the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230504/how-do-i-change-default-devise-views-paths).

Comment: for users i want to keep the same as devise provides for. but as i created a scond model (Customers) i would like to keep all the views in app/views/customers/....

Comment: You need to search for `scoped views` with Devise. [Check the README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) for some guidance. I hope it's helpful.